# When i using Ajax.Beginform() getting duplicate view , and whole form showing in targeted div

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ajaxhelper

I am new to MVC,My MVC application showing duplicated view, i used ajax.beginform() method. i added jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js as a reference in my layout page and correct version of jquery.js file still getting duplicated view. targeted div by Ajax.beginform showing whole page (with masterpage and layoutpage) in targeted div.

**Master.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootsrtap Free Admin Template - SIMINTA | Admin Dashboad Template</title>
    <!-- Core CSS - Include with every page -->
    <link href="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-big-counter.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/assets/css/main-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />


   @* <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
   @* <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--  wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- navbar top -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="navbar">
            <!-- navbar-header -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- end navbar-header -->
            <!-- navbar-top-links -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <!-- main dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <span class="top-label label label-danger">3</span><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-3x"></i>
                    </a>
                    <!-- dropdown-messages -->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong><span class=" label label-danger">Andrew Smith</span></strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong><span class=" label label-info">Jonney Depp</span></strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong><span class=" label label-success">Jonney Depp</span></strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>Read All Messages</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- end dropdown-messages -->
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <span class="top-label label label-success">4</span>  <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-3x"></i>
                    </a>
                    <!-- dropdown tasks -->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 1</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">40% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 2</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">20% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 3</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">60% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 4</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">80% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Tasks</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- end dropdown-tasks -->
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <span class="top-label label label-warning">5</span>  <i class="fa fa-bell fa-3x"></i>
                    </a>
                    <!-- dropdown alerts-->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i>New Comment
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i>3 New Followers
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>Message Sent
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i>New Task
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i>Server Rebooted
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- end dropdown-alerts -->
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i>
                    </a>
                    <!-- dropdown user-->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>User Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i>Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i>Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- end dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- end main dropdown -->
            </ul>
            <!-- end navbar-top-links -->

        </nav>
        <!-- end navbar top -->

        <!-- navbar side -->
        <nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
            <!-- sidebar-collapse -->
            <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                <!-- side-menu -->
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                    <li>
                        <!-- user image section-->
                        <div class="user-section">
                            <div class="user-section-inner">
                                <img src="assets/img/user.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <div>Jonny <strong>Deen</strong></div>
                                <div class="user-text-online">
                                    <span class="user-circle-online btn btn-success btn-circle "></span>&nbsp;Online
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--end user image section-->
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-search">
                        <!-- search section-->
                        <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <!--end search section-->
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i>Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i>Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="morris.html">Morris Charts</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- second-level-items -->
                    </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="timeline.html"><i class="fa fa-flask fa-fw"></i>Timeline</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Tables</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i>Forms</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i>UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="panels-wells.html">Panels and Wells</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="notifications.html">Notifications</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="typography.html">Typography</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="grid.html">Grid</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- second-level-items -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i>Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- third-level-items -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- second-level-items -->
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i>Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li class="selected">
                                <a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- second-level-items -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- end side-menu -->
            </div>
            <!-- end sidebar-collapse -->
        </nav>
        <!-- end navbar side -->
        <!--  page-wrapper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">

       @RenderBody();



        </div>
        <!-- end page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- end wrapper -->

    <!-- Core Scripts - Include with every page -->
    @*<script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>*@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/plugins/pace/pace.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/scripts/siminta.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Master.cshtml";
}
@model Mvcajaxtest.Models.mymodal



<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

<div class="row">
    <!-- page header -->
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">
            Forms</h1>
    </div>
    <!--end page header -->
</div>
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <!-- Form Elements -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Basic Form Elements
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" id="mine">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Page Header -->
                    <div class="col-lg-12" >
                        <h1 class="page-header">
                            Blank Page</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div >
                   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "mine",InsertionMode= InsertionMode.InsertBefore }))
                    {

                        <div class="col-lg-6" >
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                @ViewBag.msg
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>
                                    First Name</label>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.firstname, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                <p>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.firstname)
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>
                                    Last Name</label>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lastname, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.lastname)</p>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    }
                    </div>
                    <!--End Page Header -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace Mvcajaxtest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.msg = "";
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Mvcajaxtest.Models.mymodal mr)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                mr.inserttdata();
                ViewBag.msg = "Inserted";
                ModelState.Clear();
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Index.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Index.cshtml";
}
```

and in Homecontroller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Mvcajaxtest.Models.mymodal mr)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                mr.inserttdata();
                ModelState.Clear();
                @ViewBag.msg = "Inserted";
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Worked perfect for me

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
    public ContentResult Index(Mvcajaxtest.Models.mymodal mr)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            mr.inserttdata();
            ModelState.Clear();
            return Content("Inserted");
        }
        return Content("Invalid");
    }
```

Comment: Code is working pretty well but, I want to show "inserted" message on same view

Comment: Thank you got some ideas from this answer and worked successfully

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are returning the complete page on the ajax result not just the updated div. The reason are seeing the master/layout view is because you are setting it in index.cshtml on the line Layout = "~/Views/Master.cshtml"

Comment: you need to return a new view with the updated data instead of the original view. The new view should not have a layout.

Comment: normally you need to return a new view with the updated data (just the div) instead of the original view. The new view should not have a layout (Layout = null). However as you are only returning the the content "Inserted" i would change the actionresult to contentresult and instead of returning a view return "Inserted". Also looking at your code you have commented out all the jquery library links on the layout/master but adding it in on the index view. You want to add it in before bootstrap and have it in the master view not the index.

Comment: Thanks for more info but when i using content result its returning only content "Inserted" not index view , i want "inserted" message with index view